# What are the individual names of these nine different PVC fittings?

Tags: pvc

What are the individual names of these nine different PVC fittings?
[image: pvc]
<sub>(source: [pvcworkshop.com](http://www.pvcworkshop.com/Fitting17.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

From left to right, top to bottom:

- 3 way elbow
- 4 way tee
- 5 way tee
- tee
- internal cap
- cross
- 90 degree elbow
- slip sling tee
- 45 degree elbow

Since these appear to be structural PVC fittings, one source: http://www.formufit.com/structural-pvc-fittings/?sort=featured&page=1